# How to rename and pad directories with leading zeros

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, zero-padding

I'm looking for a way to batch rename multiple folders.  Basically, I need to pad it with leading zeros and make it a 6-digit

Example:

123 ---> 000123

22 ----> 000022

5678 --> 005678

The only way I know how to do it is:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b') do ren "%f" "0%f"  but this only pads it with 1 zero
```

Please help.  Any direction is appreciated  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file can be used the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-L /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /X "[0123456789][0123456789]*"') do (
    set "FolderName=00000%%I"
    set "FolderName=!FolderName:~-6!"
    if not !FolderName! == %%I ren %%I !FolderName!
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with output filtered additionally by `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background with `cmd.exe /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.

Comment: Amazing!.  Thank you so much!